# List components in a wiki page - or displaying a report's output in a wiki page

Tags: wiki, trac

I want to list all components we have in our trac system on a wiki page - any ideas? I have written a report that lists them (using distinct etc. so they only display once) - can I use this?

Part 2 - we have a custom field of "client", I then want to, on a client's wiki page, list just the components that have been used in tickets for that client - again I could do this in a report but how do I get that to display on a wiki page?

Thanks,

Amy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do it in a report, you can do it in a wiki page.  Use the `[[TicketQuery]]` macro to insert a report/query into a wiki page.  For example the following macro

```
[[TicketQuery(client=ClientA,group=component)]]
```

would display a list of tickets that were assigned to ClientA, grouped by component. See [WikiMacros](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiMacros#TicketQuery-macro) for more information about using this macro.

If you need to do more advanced queries, you can use plugins like the [SqlQueryMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/SqlQueryMacro) or [WikiTableMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WikiTableMacro) to allow you to write query the database directly (there are probably other plugins that do this sort of thing as well, these are just the ones that I can remember offhand).

To generate a list of your project's components, try the [ComponentsProcessorMacro](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/ComponentsProcessorMacro).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the report to a query and integrate that in the wiki page, see for example [TracQuery - Customizing the table format](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracQuery#Customizingthetableformat)

```
[[TicketQuery(max=3,status=closed,order=id,desc=1,format=table,col=resolution|summary|owner|reporter)]]
```